# Can the group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ be extended to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abelian-groups

We have the canonical projection $\pi:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which is a group homomorphism. The most natural way I can think of to try extending this to a group homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ would be to define 
$$
\phi \left( \frac ab \right) = \pi(a)
$$
where $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. Then $\phi$ agrees with $\pi$ on the integers, but $\phi$ isn't a group homomorphism, because
$$
1 = \phi \left( 1 \right) = \phi \left( \frac 12 + \frac 12\right) \neq \phi \left( \frac 12 \right) + \phi\left( \frac 12 \right) = \pi(1) + \pi(1) = 2 = 0
$$
Is is just true that $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) = 0$, in which case such an extension is hopeless?

Comment: Yes it is true that $\hom(\Bbb Q,\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)=0$. If $\phi$ were any homomorphism and $\phi(x)$ were ever nonzero, what could $\phi(x/2)$ be, since $\phi(x/2)+\phi(x/2)=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to consider additive group homomorphisms, where the second map is the canonical projection:
$$\Bbb Q\to \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$$
First we have to deal with mapping $(\Bbb Q,+)\to (\Bbb Z,+)$.

Consider $\varphi: \mathbb Q \rightarrow \mathbb Z$, and assume that $\varphi$ is a nontrivial map. Now, let $n$ be the smallest positive integer in the image of $\varphi$, and pick $\frac{a}{b} \in \varphi^{-1}(n)$. Then
$$n=\varphi\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\varphi(a/2b+a/2b)=\varphi(a/2b)+\varphi(a/2b),$$
and hence $\varphi(a/2b)=\frac{n}{2}$. But we assumed $n$ was the smallest positive integer in the image, and hence no nontrivial map exists.